# check all checkboxes javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to have all checkboxes checked (true) when the user clicks on "All" button.  I tried this, firstly just to see if "Anglais" could be checked clicking on "All" :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="anglais"  id="anglais"  value="Anglais"  /> Anglais
<input type="checkbox" name="allemand" id="allemand" value="Allemand" /> Allemand
<input type="checkbox" name="espagnol" id="espagnol" value="Espagnol" /> Espagnol
<input type="checkbox" name="francais" id="francais" value="Francais" /> Francais
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkedAll()" name="all"      id="all"      value="Tous"     /> Tous
```

My Javascript :

```
function checkedAll () {
var checked = false;
var all = document.getElementById('all');
if (checked == false) {
    checked = true
}
else {
    checked = false
}
var ang = document.getElementById('anglais').checked
if (ang == true) {
    ang.checked = true;
    }
```

But the button(s) are not checked when I click on All.  I think I don't understand exactly how to use the .checked method..
Maybe, some of my code has not logic, because it was from this example : 
https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/select-all-checkbox.php

Comment: Hint: What `ang` is?

Comment: Okay. It's a variable. What does it store?

Comment: Does it stores the actual status (true / false ? ) of checked for 'anglais' id ?

Comment: Well, according to your code - it's storing a boolean. But then 2 lines later you do `ang.checked = true;` like you're expecting it's not a boolean but a dom element there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple modifications:

- Pass in the `all` checkbox to the `checkedAll` method (this allows you to reference it without having to re-find it).
- Used `document.getElementsByTagName` to find the other checkboxes, but you could just as easily use `document.getElementById` for each one (`anglais`, `allemand`, etc.)
- Set every other checkbox's `checked` status to the `all.checked` value. No need for a true/false comparison.

```js
function checkedAll(allCheckbox){
  var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < allCheckboxes.length; i++){
    var curCheckbox = allCheckboxes[i];
    if (curCheckbox.id != 'all'){
      curCheckbox.checked = allCheckbox.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="anglais"  id="anglais"  value="Anglais"  /> Anglais
<input type="checkbox" name="allemand" id="allemand" value="Allemand" /> Allemand
<input type="checkbox" name="espagnol" id="espagnol" value="Espagnol" /> Espagnol
<input type="checkbox" name="francais" id="francais" value="Francais" /> Francais
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkedAll(this)" name="all" id="all" value="Tous" /> Tous
```

The more explicit way would be:

```js
function checkedAll(){
  var isAllChecked = document.getElementById('all').checked;
  
  // Set the other checkboxes .checked property based on the
  // .checked status of the `all` checkbox
  document.getElementById('anglais').checked = isAllChecked;
  document.getElementById('allemand').checked = isAllChecked;
  document.getElementById('espagnol').checked = isAllChecked;
  document.getElementById('francais').checked = isAllChecked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="anglais"  id="anglais"  value="Anglais"  /> Anglais
<input type="checkbox" name="allemand" id="allemand" value="Allemand" /> Allemand
<input type="checkbox" name="espagnol" id="espagnol" value="Espagnol" /> Espagnol
<input type="checkbox" name="francais" id="francais" value="Francais" /> Francais
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkedAll()" name="all" id="all" value="Tous" /> Tous
```